# How to reset Apple ID privacy question and answer?

Tags: apple-id

I has an Apple ID for publishing app to TestFlight, it has no iPhone, no two-factor authentications. And I forget the privacy question and answers.

When I choose that I forget the answers, and want to reset the questions and answers, then Apple page **needs me to answer the privacy question to reset the privacy question and answer.**

Because I had forgot the answers for privacy questions. When I want to reset the privacy questions, the Apple web page insists that I had to answers the privacy question, in order to reset it.

So, I cannot reset the privacy questions for apple-id. Any suggestions ?

---

#### Update:

I had tried to use a phone and tried to enable two factor authentication. But when I want to enable two factor authentication, it ask me about privacy question and answers. 
(ps: I put the sim card in to the phone, and it still insists to answer the privacy questions to enable two factor authentication, or to reset the privacy question, or to reset the password.)

I don't remember the answers for privacy questions. When I want to reset the privacy question / answers, Apple asks me the privacy questions / answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, I tried to log in with an iPhone after my long vacation. On the phone, when I want to enable 2-factor authentication, it doesn't ask me about privacy questions. It asked me about the phone-number, and then sent 6-digits numbers to the phone.

So, I had enabled 2-factor authentications.

Maybe, **Time is the best solution.**